# Compile error caused by the position of -lSOME_LIBRARY

Tags: gcc, linker

I'm compiling KDBUS in my machine (x86-64, ubuntu 14.04). But this question is actually not related. This is a example. The first command fails, but the second succeeds. The success and failure depend on the order of -lm, and -lm. I saw this kinds of problem before. I could solved that problem manually. By this time, I want to know if there is a way to the first command succeeds without modifying the order of -lXXX ridiculously. Is there someone who know the way?

## 1.

gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -g -include /include/uapi/linux/memfd.h -I../samples/ -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-parameter -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wcast-align -Wsign-compare -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pthread **-lm -lcap** kdbus-enum.o kdbus-util.o kdbus-test.o test-activator.o test-attach-flags.o test-benchmark.o test-bus.o test-chat.o test-connection.o test-daemon.o test-endpoint.o test-fd.o test-free.o test-match.o test-message.o test-metadata-ns.o test-monitor.o test-names.o test-policy.o test-policy-ns.o test-policy-priv.o test-sync.o test-timeout.o -o kdbus-test

kdbus-util.o: In function `do_cap_get_flag':

/harddisk/git/public/KDBUS/kdbus/test/kdbus-util.c:1525: undefined reference to `cap_get_flag'

kdbus-util.o: In function `test_is_capable':

/harddisk/git/public/KDBUS/kdbus/test/kdbus-util.c:1550: undefined reference to `cap_get_proc'

/harddisk/git/public/KDBUS/kdbus/test/kdbus-util.c:1570: undefined reference to `cap_free'

test-benchmark.o: In function `dump_stats':

/harddisk/git/public/KDBUS/kdbus/test/test-benchmark.c:62: undefined reference to `sqrt'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

## .2

gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -g -include /include/uapi/linux/memfd.h -I../samples/ -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-parameter -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wcast-align -Wsign-compare -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pthread kdbus-enum.o kdbus-util.o  **-lcap** kdbus-test.o test-activator.o test-attach-flags.o test-benchmark.o **-lm** test-bus.o test-chat.o test-connection.o test-daemon.o test-endpoint.o test-fd.o test-free.o test-match.o test-message.o test-metadata-ns.o test-monitor.o test-names.o test-policy.o test-policy-ns.o test-policy-priv.o test-sync.o test-timeout.o -o kdbus-test

## Added 1.

```
kdbus-test: $(OBJS)
        @echo '  TARGET_LD $@'
        @echo $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
        $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

This is the makefile for the above compile command. I think that this kinds of makefiles are common. How should I modify this makefile to work?

## Added 2.

```
kdbus-test: $(OBJS)
        @echo '  TARGET_LD $@'
        @echo $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
        $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

After I added the above additional question, I found that this code works. After the comment from Mike Kinghan and this working code, is it the right way to put the $LDFLAGS after object files generally?

Comment: A library must occur in the linkage sequence *after* the objects that require symbol definitions from it. Otherwise you have unresolved symbol errors. There's nothing ridiculous about getting linkage order right.

Comment: Is this real example? I mean, there actually are build systems that puts libraries *before* object files list?

Comment: @keltar User's foot is often shot by hacks or commandline args that put libs into `LDFLAGS` instead of `LIBS`, or all-and-sundry in `C[XX]FLAGS`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This comment window is too small, so I added some more question on the main window. Can you take a look for that?

Comment: @DerekHwang libraries are usually put to separate variable, e.g. `LIBS`. Yes it almost always have to be specified last, after object files or local static libraries. `LDFLAGS` are commonly used to specify libraries paths and linker specials, but except in some extreme cases I still see no good reason for it to come before object files.

Comment: Thanks for all comment.To sum up, the library link info(-lXXX) must be put in the variable 'LIBS' and this variable should be placed after the object files.